# Java array loop round

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array in Java and want to find the next element in an array.

I want to keep getting the next element in the array. Instead of getting to the end of the array and stopping, how can I make it so it will loop round to the beginning of the array again and continue doing this?

Comment: Show the code you have so far. This is quite broad and vague. You want the loop to loop forever?

Comment: Reset the index variable back to `0` when you reach the end. You know, using an `if` statement. It really can be that simple.

Comment: @David992 This question is kinda weird, you mean you want to implement an infinite loop? What is your condition to end the loop? You may want to tell us why you needed such loop.

Answer (score 0):

For example, let's assume we have an array of strings.

Let's consider some of the approaches.

## Using explicit index check

Another approach is to use the explicit check that the index is going beyond the maximum value and reset it to keep the index in the range as required.

Please consider the following draft implementation:

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final String[] words = new String[] {
            "Hello",
            "World",
            "Goodbye",
            "World"
        };

        int index = 0;
        while (index < words.length) {
            System.out.printf(
                "Index: %d; Value: %s.%n",
                index,
                words[index]
            );

            ++index;
            if (index == words.length) {
                index = 0;
            }

            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

## Using modulo operation

Please consider the following draft implementation:

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final String[] words = new String[] {
            "Hello",
            "World",
            "Goodbye",
            "World"
        };

        int index = 0;
        while (index < words.length) {
            System.out.printf(
                "Index: %d; Value: %s.%n",
                index,
                words[index]
            );

            ++index;
            index %= words.length;

            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

The key here is the use of the modulo operation (finding the remainder after division) to keep the index in the range as required.

## Notes for both approaches

1. There is an infinite loop, if the array is not empty.
2. There is the `index < words.length` as the while-loop condition to handle an empty array properly.

Hope this helps.